# Query in Kadane's Algorithm

Tags: c, arrays, algorithm

I am going through the Kadane's Algorithm for Maximum sub-array problem.Now what I understand from the statement the algo that we have find a **sub-array** . Does sub-array include whole array itself.

Actually I was trying following program

```
    int main(void)
    {
    int arr[9]={5,6,-4,-1,-2,1,5,3};

    int i,n,max_last =0,max_mid =0;

    for(i=0;i<8;i++)
    {
      max_mid = max_mid + arr[i];
      printf("max_mid =%d\n",max_mid); 

      if ( max_mid < 0)
              max_mid =0;

      if( max_mid > max_last)
              max_last = max_mid;
     }

      printf("val=%d",max_last);
        return 0;
     }
```

Here it is giving 13 as final answer which is the sum of all element of array.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, any continuous sub-array could be a solution, including the whole array.

Note that empty sub-array might be valid solution too (for all negative numbers algorithm gives max sum result 0)

Comment: +1. It's exactly the same as how mathematicians say a whole set is a subset of itself. A subset that is strictly smaller is called a *proper subset*, so I suppose we could use "proper sub-array" to refer to a sub-array which *isn't* the whole array.

Comment: I think there is no need to separate solution for "proper sub-arrays", because algorithm is intended for general case, and nobody claimed that requirement.